# Ground Zero: chat user 0 throwing error

Tags: bug, chat, deleted-accounts

After a user was deleted from this site, their existing chat messages link to https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/0 which sadly generates the infamous "workin on ur problemz" lolcat.

Observed here for example:

> [image]

Worth to mention, in the transcript the name is not clickable, so the bug exists only when actually inside a room.

Comment: Cannot reproduce anymore. The link to user profile 0 now leads to a 404 instead of a server error, and chat messages from deleted users are now unlinked.

Comment: @Sonic were you in a room while a user who posted a message was deleted? Like I mentioned, in the transcript it's fine. However glad they fixed the error, now it's only a very minor bug.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're talking about. I think that the broken link is a rather minor issue, since clicking a deleted user in the room leads to a message "no user data available" without an actual text link. Only if I right-click the user link and choose the option to open in a new tab do I actually navigate to the user 0 URL. In any case, this question isn't reporting the presence of such a link, but the server error caused by going there, and that's no longer reproducible.