# Who is this user #0?

Tags: support, user-accounts, stackexchange.com, network-profile

I typed https://stackexchange.com/users/0 and found there is a user with #0 named RAKESH KUMAR.

[image]

Community user is [user #-1](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)
Jeff Atwood is [user #1](https://stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

Who is this [user #0](https://stackexchange.com/users/0/rakesh-kumar)? Are they a co-founder or developer of SE or SO? Or is this some kind of bug? They don't have any SE account (may be deleted later ?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11859925/rakesh-kumar

Comment: @Luuklag strangely enough also this user: https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/147015/tyler-larsen (found with a quick SEDE query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1393076?accountid=0)

Comment: Related "user 0" Q&As: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352629/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286756/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325779/282094

Comment: Thank you Luuklag, rene and Rob. But how that user was assigned a number 0? According to this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325415/whats-the-difference-between-community-and-user0/325779#325779) there's no user with #0 in SE. This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11859925/rakesh-kumar) joined SO 1 yr, 8 months ago. Then how did they get a number 0?

Comment: And this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325415/whats-the-difference-between-community-and-user0/325779#325779) was posted before the user with ID #0 created their account. So is this a bug?

Comment: Also there’s raw 404 page for [+](https://stackexchange.com/+), not the same as regular 404 page. E.g. for [-](https://stackexchange.com/-).

Comment: @Luuklag btw, RAKESH KUMAR has more than 1000 profile views on SO. Large enough for user without any action. Even after noting here.

Comment: @rene I searched for the name on SO and then matched one from the 16 pages based on the profile image. It appears to be a verry common name. But perhaps this is related to account merges?

Comment: @Luuklag yeah, account merge is possible but IIRC there is some race condition and db inserts taking place that are not all governed by a transaction. I expect it didn't create the network account on time and then the accountid  stayed at is default, being 0. And with that the userprofile got inserted in the db with 0 as accountid. Maybe there are networkaccounts that have 0 user profiles linked to them. [They can't handle success](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207388/why-is-the-handlesuccess-method-such-a-terrible-one)

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/users/0/jon-skeet

Comment: Looks like they're gone now...

Comment: @Ollie Yes. They haven't been using SO since 2019, and their account is gone now! Was it deleted by mods? 

Comment: @Ak. See below, I guess.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There were actually two users with a network account Id set to 0, both of them created at about the same time. I can only imagine that there was some short-lived glitch in the database back in 2019 that has not reoccurred. Both the profiles have now been deleted, given it's pretty much impossible to track down a real account or what happened without a correct account Id to investigate.